# Why are my character and word counts off?

Tags: java, regex, string, text, word-count

Given the following string:

> String text = "The woods are\nlovely,\t\tdark and deep.";

I want all whitespace treated as a single character. So for instance, the `\n` is 1 char. The `\t\t` should also be 1 char. With that logic, I count 36 characters and 7 words. But when I run this through the following code:

```
String text = "The woods are\nlovely,\t\tdark and deep.";

int numNewCharacters = 0;
for(int i=0; i < text.length(); i++)
    if(!Character.isWhitespace(text.charAt(i)))
        numNewCharacters++;

int numNewWords = text.split("\\s").length;

// Prints "30"
System.out.println("Chars:" + numNewCharacters);

// Prints "8"
System.out.println("Words:" + numNewWords);
```

It's telling me that there are 30 characters and 8 words. Any ideas as to why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Print out each non white space character you find in the first loop, and all the elements of the split array - it should be pretty obvious then. If its not, edit your question with what you found and we can help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are matching on individual whitespaces. Instead you could match on *one or more*:

```
text.split("\\s+")
```

Comment: Thanks @Reimeus (+1) - that solves word count - what about character count? Thanks again!

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys For a dirty solution you can use `text.replaceAll("\\s+"," ").length` - which raplaces all whitespace matches on one or more to just one, and prints the length of it.

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys, yes, as suggested by Pesci, I think probably using `text.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").length()` is probably the way to go. In this this case using the `Character` methods would be more cumbersome :)

Answer (score 0):

You are counting only non white space characters in the first loop - so not counting space etc at all. Then 30 is the right answer. As for the second - I suspect split is treating consecutive white spaces as distinct, so there is a "null" word between the two tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Reimueus has already solved your word count problem:

```
text.split("\\s+")
```

And your character count is corret.  Newlines `\n` and tabs `\t` are considered whitespace.  If you don't want them to be, you can implement your own `isWhitespace` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution to counting words and characters:

```
    System.out.println("Characters: " + text.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").length());
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^\\s]+", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(text);
    int wordCount = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        wordCount ++;
    }
    System.out.println("Words: "+ wordCount);
```

Character count is accomplished by replacing all whitespaces groups to a single space and just taking the resulting string's length;

For word count we create a pattern that will match any char group which does not contain a whitespace. You could use **\\w+** pattern here, but it will match only alphanumeric characters and underscore. Note also **Pattern.MULTILINE** parameter.